# How to convert daywise(daily) data to monthly data using R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have day-wise data of interest rate of 15 years from 01-01-2000 to 01-01-2015.
I want to convert this data to monthly data, which only having month and year.

I want to take mean of the values of all the days in a month and make it one value of that month. 
How can I do this in R.

```
> str(mibid)
'data.frame':   4263 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Days: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date: Date, format: "2000-01-03" "2000-01-04" "2000-01-05" "2000-01-06" ...
 $ BID : num  8.82 8.82 8.88 8.79 8.78 8.8 8.81 8.82 8.86 8.78 ...
 $ I.S : num  0.092 0.0819 0.0779 0.0801 0.074 0.0766 0.0628 0.0887 0.0759 0.073 ...
 $ BOR : num  9.46 9.5 9.52 9.36 9.33 9.37 9.42 9.39 9.4 9.33 ...
 $ R.S : num  0.0822 0.0817 0.0828 0.0732 0.084 0.0919 0.0757 0.0725 0.0719 0.0564 ...
> head(mibid)
  Days       Date  BID    I.S  BOR    R.S
1    1 2000-01-03 8.82 0.0920 9.46 0.0822
2    2 2000-01-04 8.82 0.0819 9.50 0.0817
3    3 2000-01-05 8.88 0.0779 9.52 0.0828
4    4 2000-01-06 8.79 0.0801 9.36 0.0732
5    5 2000-01-07 8.78 0.0740 9.33 0.0840
6    6 2000-01-08 8.80 0.0766 9.37 0.0919
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with xts:

```
set.seed(21)
mibid <- data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()-100:1,
  BID=rnorm(100, 8, 0.1), I.S=rnorm(100, 0.08, 0.01),
  BOR=rnorm(100, 9, 0.1), R.S=rnorm(100, 0.08, 0.01))
require(xts)
# convert to xts
xmibid <- xts(mibid[,-1], mibid[,1])
# aggregate
agg_xmibid <- apply.monthly(xmibid, colMeans)
# convert back to data.frame
agg_mibid <- data.frame(Date=index(agg_xmibid), agg_xmibid, row.names=NULL)
head(agg_mibid)
#         Date      BID        I.S      BOR        R.S
# 1 2015-04-30 8.079301 0.07189111 9.074807 0.06819096
# 2 2015-05-31 7.987479 0.07888328 8.999055 0.08090253
# 3 2015-06-30 8.043845 0.07885779 9.018338 0.07847999
# 4 2015-07-31 7.990822 0.07799489 8.980492 0.08162038
# 5 2015-08-07 8.000414 0.08535749 9.044867 0.07755017
```

Answer (score 2):

A small example of how this might be done using `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
set.seed(321)
dat <- data.frame(day=seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), length.out=200, by="day"), 
       x = rnorm(200), 
       y = rexp(200))
head(dat)

         day          x         y
1 2010-01-01  1.7049032 2.6286754
2 2010-01-02 -0.7120386 0.3916089
3 2010-01-03 -0.2779849 0.1815379
4 2010-01-04 -0.1196490 0.1234461
5 2010-01-05 -0.1239606 2.2237404
6 2010-01-06  0.2681838 0.3217511

require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)
dat %>%
  mutate(year = year(day), 
         monthnum = month(day),
         month = month(day, label=T)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  arrange(year, monthnum) %>%
  select(-monthnum) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x), 
            y = mean(y))

 Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
 Groups: year

  year month           x         y
1 2010   Jan  0.02958633 0.9387509
2 2010   Feb  0.07711820 1.0985411
3 2010   Mar -0.06429982 1.2395438
4 2010   Apr -0.01787658 1.3627864
5 2010   May  0.19131861 1.1802712
6 2010   Jun -0.04894075 0.8224855
7 2010   Jul -0.22410057 1.1749863
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `data.table` which has several very convenient datetime functions. Using the data of @SamThomas:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(year(day), month(day))]
```

this gives:

```
   year month           x         y
1: 2010     1  0.02958633 0.9387509
2: 2010     2  0.07711820 1.0985411
3: 2010     3 -0.06429982 1.2395438
4: 2010     4 -0.01787658 1.3627864
5: 2010     5  0.19131861 1.1802712
6: 2010     6 -0.04894075 0.8224855
7: 2010     7 -0.22410057 1.1749863
```

On the data of @JoshuaUlrich:

```
setDT(mibid)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(year(Date), month(Date))]
```

gives:

```
   year month      BID        I.S      BOR        R.S
1: 2015     5 7.997178 0.07794925 8.999625 0.08062426
2: 2015     6 8.034805 0.07940600 9.019823 0.07823314
3: 2015     7 7.989371 0.07822263 8.996015 0.08195401
4: 2015     8 8.010541 0.08364351 8.982793 0.07748399
```

If you want the names of the months instead of numbers, you will have to include `[, day:=as.IDate(day)]` after the `setDT()` part and use `months` instead of `month`:

```
setDT(mibid)[, Date:=as.IDate(Date)][, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(year(Date), months(Date))]
```

---

*Note*: Especially on larger datasets, `data.table` will probably be (a lot) faster then the other two solutions.

Comment: Very useful, thanks!